# Postgresql and Tablespaces no such file

Tags: postgresql

I am having issues with postgresql 14  and 2 tablespaces:

```
db=# select * from stock_move;
ERROR:  could not open file "pg_tblspc/32192/PG_14_202107181/16384/32197": No such file or directory
db=# 

db=# select * from stock_picking;
ERROR:  could not open file "pg_tblspc/32191/PG_14_202107181/16384/32194": No such file or directory
db=#
```

Everything was normal, but we decided to scale the server and when we restarted it came up with the error described above. There is also another tablespace, but it is working normally.

Tablespaces:

```
postgres@database-server:/mnt$ ls -l
total 12
drwx------ 4 postgres postgres 4096 Jan  9 05:33 stock_move
drwx------ 4 postgres postgres 4096 Jan  9 05:34 stock_move_line
drwx------ 4 postgres postgres 4096 Jan  9 05:34 stock_picking
postgres@database-server:/mnt$
```

These tablespaces are put in a partition for each one, each partition is mounted in /etc/fstab

```
/dev/nvme1n1  /mnt/stock_move            ext4 defaults 0 1
/dev/nvme2n1  /mnt/stock_move_line       ext4 defaults 0 1
/dev/nvme3n1  /mnt/stock_picking         ext4 defaults 0 1
```

It seems that postgres tries to search for these files but they do not exist (32197, 32194).

```
root@database-server:/mnt/stock_picking/PG_14_202107181/16384# ll
total 1939392
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres       4096 Jan 13 01:06 ./
drwx------ 3 postgres postgres       4096 Jan  9 05:39 ../
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 1073741824 Jan 11 17:26 32197
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  911597568 Jan 12 00:01 32197.1
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres     507904 Jan 11 23:16 32197_fsm
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres      65536 Jan 11 17:17 32197_vm
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres          0 Jan  9 05:39 32198
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres       8192 Jan  9 05:39 32199
root@database-server:/mnt/stock_picking/PG_14_202107181/16384#
```

and

```
root@database-server:/mnt/stock_move/PG_14_202107181/16384# ll
total 1200276
drwx------ 2 postgres postgres       4096 Jan 13 01:10 ./
drwx------ 3 postgres postgres       4096 Jan  9 05:36 ../
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres   38191104 Jan 12 00:01 32194
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres      32768 Jan 11 19:26 32194_fsm
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres       8192 Jan  9 17:39 32194_vm
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres          0 Jan  9 05:36 32195
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres       8192 Jan  9 05:36 32196
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres 1073741824 Jan 11 16:55 32203
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres  116727808 Jan 12 00:01 32203.1
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres     311296 Jan 11 23:43 32203_fsm
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres      40960 Jan 11 23:47 32203_vm
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres          0 Jan  9 05:44 32204
-rw------- 1 postgres postgres       8192 Jan  9 05:44 32205
root@database-server:/mnt/stock_move/PG_14_202107181/16384#
```

and pg_tblspc links

```
root@database-server:/var/lib/postgresql/14/main/pg_tblspc# ll
total 8
drwx------  2 postgres postgres 4096 Jan  9 05:34 ./
drwx------ 19 postgres postgres 4096 Jan 13 01:15 ../
lrwxrwxrwx  1 postgres postgres   18 Jan  9 05:33 32191 -> /mnt/stock_picking/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 postgres postgres   15 Jan  9 05:34 32192 -> /mnt/stock_move/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 postgres postgres   20 Jan  9 05:34 32193 -> /mnt/stock_move_line/
root@database-server:/var/lib/postgresql/14/main/pg_tblspc#
```

From here on I don't know what to do.

Comment: use sudo or su to become the "postgres" user, and then try to access those file going through the symlinks e.g. `ls -l /var/lib/postgresql/14/main/pg_tblspc/32191/PG_14_202107181/16384/32194`

Answer (score 0):

The only good explanation is that someone or something deleted the files that make up this table. This is the time to restore your backup.